# When should one use Redis as a Primary Database and Elastic Search

Tags: database, mongodb, redis, microservices

I have following scenario, others may have different. How should we decide between Redis as persistent primary database and Elastic Search. 
In a micro-service, database has lots of read requests, in comparison to write request. Also my data will have only 8-10 columns or keys in terms of JSON (Simple data structure).

If my database hardly gets write request in respect to read request, why should we not use Redis as persistent Database. I went through Redis Office document and found why should we use it as persistent database [[Goodbye Cache: Redis as a Primary Database]](https://redislabs.com/blog/goodbye-cache-redis-as-a-primary-database/)

But still not convinced fully to use it as a Primary Database

Comment: how much is "lots of read requests" in request / second?

Comment: Lots of read = 10000 read request/sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would depend on your application and what it does internally. But assuming you don't need particularly complicated queries to get the data (no complex filtering, for example) and you can fit all your information in memory, I see Redis as a completely valid alternative to a traditional database.

If you want the strongest possible guarantees Redis can offer, you'd want to enable both RDB and AOF persistence options (read https://redis.io/topics/persistence).

The big advantage of a set-up like this is you can trust Redis to improve the throughput of the application, and maintain a very good level of performance over time, even with a growing dataset.